# How to stop a custom ThrowHelper from appearing in your StackTrace?

Tags: c#, .net

A pattern you'll find in the .net base class library is that of the ThrowHelper.  In essence it cuts down the amount of byte code per method.

Anyway, I was wondering if there was an attribute directive to stop an error caused in the throw Helper from stopping inside the helper.  I'd prefer the debugger to stop at the calling line.

i.e.

```
  ThrowHelper.ThrowAnException ()
```

rather than inside ThrowAnException()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also mark your throwing method with an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx):

```
class ThrowHelper
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void Throw()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then debugger will not enter this method.

Comment: +1: that looks good.  Is it possible to tag at the class level instead?

Comment: Yes you can put it on class level.

Comment: is there a way to stop this showing up in the stack trace for unit tests?  That's the only remaining annoyance now.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way that would allow you to modify stack trace of an exception.

Answer (score 5):

You could make the helper method not actually throw the exception, just create it. The stack trace will point to the throw statement in your real method, not to anything in ThrowHelper.

```
throw ThrowHelper.CreateAnException();
```

Comment: okay.  That would work, but sometimes throw helpers have ultra basic logic inside, so that's not going to be useful in this case.

Comment: It would consolidate the logic for the exception messages and that type of thing, though.

Comment: This is the approach Microsoft actually recommends.  See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030(v=vs.100).aspx) and scroll down:  "The helper method must not throw the exception or the stack trace will not accurately reflect the call stack that caused the exception."

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or exclude a method from being included in your stack trace by decorating the method or class with the `[System.Diagnostics.StackTraceHidden]` attribute.

The `StackTraceHidden` attribute was introduced in .NET 6.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktracehiddenattribute

> Types and Methods attributed with StackTraceHidden will be omitted from the stack trace text shown in StackTrace.ToString() and Exception.StackTrace

Example:

```cs
[System.Diagnostics.StackTraceHidden]
public static class Throw
{
    public static T IfNull<T>(
        [NotNull] T obj,
        string? errorMessage)
    {
        return obj == null
            ? throw new Exception(errorMessage)
            : obj;
    }
}
```